# Exception not printing stacktrace for NullPointerException

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, scriptlet

My error page looks like this:

```
<div class="hideShow" style="width:99%; text-align: center;  display: none;" >
            <UL><LI> <strong><%=exception%> </strong></LI></UL>
</div>
```

and my scriptlet

```
<%
  ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(bytes, true);
  exception.printStackTrace(writer);
  exception.printStackTrace(System.err);
%>
```

So in the UI I see `NUllPointerException` however my console shows the entire stacktrace.
How can I see the entire stacktrace in the UI too.

I used the scriplet code like below,

```
<div class="hideShow" style="width:99%; text-align: center;  display: none;" >
            <UL><LI> <strong><%=exception.printStackTrace(writer)%> </strong></LI></UL>
</div>
```

but i get this error in console:

```
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

Any suggestions on how to show the stacktrace for null pointer that I see in console.
It works well for other type of exceptions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exception.printStackTrace(writer)` doesn't return a value, so it can't print it to the `out`.

Change code

```
<div class="hideShow" style="width:99%; text-align: center;  display: none;" >
            <UL><LI> <strong><%exception.printStackTrace(response.getWriter());%> </strong></LI></UL>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried the above and getting this exception now "The method printStackTrace(PrintStream) in the type Throwable is not applicable for the arguments (JspWriter)"

Comment: Are you OK with PrintWriter?

Comment: I passed PrintWrite object too and got this error " "The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)""

Comment: I don't understand you, don't use method print. Use my answer.

Comment: Sorry the page was not refreshed. Im getting the stacktrace now. Thanks much!